# The file “xxx” couldn’t be saved in the folder “xxx” - Not Saving NSImage of NSOpenPanel selected url in swift macos

Tags: swift, macos, swift5, nsimage, nsopenpanel

I am new with MACOS Development and making one app. In my application, I am opening NSOpenPanel and selecting a folder or any directory(like download, document) then NSOPenPanel begin method gives me the selected URL. I want to save multiple images on that selected URL but unable to achieve that facing this error.

The file “xxx” couldn’t be saved in the folder “xxx”.

```
@IBAction func menuExportTapped(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        openPanel.title = NSLocalizedString("change_the_folder", comment: "")
        openPanel.runModal()
        openPanel.begin { [weak self] (result) -> Void in
            if result == .OK {
                self?.myImage?.writePNG(toURL: openPanel.url!)
            } else {
                openPanel.close()
            }
        }
}
```

I tested writePNG code it's working fine.

```
extension NSImage {
public func writePNG(toURL url: URL) {
        
        guard let data = tiffRepresentation,
              let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: data),
              let imgData = rep.representation(using: .png, properties: [.compressionFactor : NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0)]) else {
            
            Swift.print("\(self) Error Function '\(#function)' Line: \(#line) No tiff rep found for image writing to \(url)")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try imgData.write(to: url)
        }catch let error {
            Swift.print("\(self) Error Function '\(#function)' Line: \(#line) \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. Thank You!

Comment: The following doesn't make sense.  "I am opening NSOpenPanel and selecting a folder or any directory then NSOPenPanel begin method gives me the selected URL. I want to save an image on that selected URL"

Comment: If you want to save a file you better use `NSSavePanel`. The problem is that the current configuration of `NSOpenPanel` returns the URL of a **directory** and you cannot replace a directory with a file. That's what the error says. At least you have to append a proper file name and file extension to the directory URL.

Comment: I want to save mulitple images of selected path. I check with the NSSavePanel it's not working with multiple files. Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: @ElTomato please check now I update my question. I want to save multiple images, not one. thanks

Comment: You have to use `NSOpenPanel`, then.  The following doesn't make sense, right, since you are selecting a folder?  self?.myImage?.writePNG(toURL: openPanel.url!)

Comment: Yes, I am selecting the folder at that selected URL path. I want to save my all images there! Is it possible? Anything wrong I am doing here? Please suggest me. thank you

Comment: *Please suggest me*. I did: ***At least you have to append a proper file name and file extension to the directory URL***

Comment: Okay, I will try this and let you know. thank you so much

Comment: @vadian thank you so much. Now, it's working fine for me!